# how can I add datetime stamp to zip file when unload data from snowflake to s3?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-task

I want to be able to add a timestamp the filename I'm writing to s3. So far I've been able to write files to AWS S3 using example below. Can someone guide me as to how do I go about putting datetime stamp in the file name?

```
copy into     @s3bucket/something.csv.gz
from (select * from  mytable)
file_format = (type=csv  FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"' compression='gzip' )
single=true
header=TRUE;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you not able to specify the file name here?  @s3bucket/datetime_something.csv.gz

Or are you trying to do it dynamically?

Comment: I want to be able to do it dynamically, so that when the script runs it'll automatically create that datetime_something.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [syntax for defining a path](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html) inside of a stage or location portion of the `COPY INTO` statement does not allow for functions to dynamically define it in SQL.

However, you can use a [stored procedure](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-procedure.html) to accomplish building dynamic queries, using [JavaScript Date APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and [some string formatting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Here's a very trivial example for your use-case, with some code [adapted from another question](https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009SCn9KSAT/i-am-trying-to-get-a-stored-procedure-to-execute-a-copy-into-command-finishes-successfully-but-the-copy-does-not-happen):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE COPY_INTO_PROCEDURE_EXAMPLE()
RETURNS VARIANT
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
    var rows = [];

    var n = new Date();
    // May need refinement to zero-pad some values or achieve a specific format
    var datetime = `${n.getFullYear()}-${n.getMonth() + 1}-${n.getDate()}-${n.getHours()}-${n.getMinutes()}-${n.getSeconds()}`;

    var st = snowflake.createStatement({
        sqlText: `COPY INTO '@s3bucket/${datetime}_something.csv.gz' FROM (SELECT * FROM  mytable) FILE_FORMAT=(TYPE=CSV  FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY='"' COMPRESSION='gzip') SINGLE=TRUE HEADER=TRUE;`
    });

    var result = st.execute();
    result.next();
    rows.push(result.getColumnValue(1))

    return rows;
$$
```

To execute, run:

```sql
CALL COPY_INTO_PROCEDURE_EXAMPLE();
```

The above is missing perfected date format handling (zero padding months, days, hours, minutes, seconds), error handling (if the `COPY INTO` fails), parameterisation of input query, etc. but it should give a general idea on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

As Sharvan Kumar suggests above, Snowflake now support this:

```
-- Partition the unloaded data by date and hour. Set ``32000000`` (32 MB) as the upper size limit of each file to be generated in parallel per thread.
copy into @%t1
  from t1
  partition by ('date=' || to_varchar(dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || '/hour=' || to_varchar(date_part(hour, ts))) -- Concatenate labels and column values to output meaningful filenames
  file_format = (type=parquet)
  max_file_size = 32000000
  header=true;

list @%t1
```

Answer (score 0):

This features is not supported yet in snowflake, however will be coming soon.