# Adding current date in create script for Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a requirement where I have to create tables with the date/datetime in the table name when they were created dynamically. Wondering if this option is possible in Snowflake?

E.g. I would need something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE someNewTable_YYYYMMDD
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using [SQL variables](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/session-variables.html#using-sql-to-initialize-variables-in-a-session) and the [`IDENTIFIER`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifier-literal.html) keyword.

Here's an example that adds the current date into the table-name:

```sql
SET table_name=(SELECT 'someNewTable_' || TO_VARCHAR(CURRENT_DATE(), 'YYYYMMDD'));

CREATE TABLE IDENTIFIER($table_name) (col STRING);
```

For more complicated tasks where using `IDENTIFIER` keyword is inadequate, you can also use stored procedures [as shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61597017/how-can-i-add-datetime-stamp-to-zip-file-when-unload-data-from-snowflake-to-s3/61614755#61614755).