# Regex Expression for Snowflake Pattern

Tags: regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, regex-group

I have a list of files in the `s3` bucket as below. I want to load only the current date files, for example, 
I want to get all file_a.csv which are under 2020/06/09, similarly get all file_b.csv under same 2020/06/09

I tried out the syntax but this gets me all files from all dates 
`select metadata$filename from @stage/snflk/ts/(file_format=>CSV_SKIP_HEADER,pattern=>'.*/file_a.*[.]csv')`

```
snflk/ts/ts-prod/2020/06/08/file_a.csv
snflk/ts/ts-prod/2020/06/09/file_a.csv
snflk/ts/ts-prod3/2020/06/08/file_a.csv
snflk/ts/ts-prod3/2020/06/09/file_a.csv
snflk/ts/ts-prod2/2020/06/08/file_a.csv
snflk/ts/ts-prod2/2020/06/09/file_a.csv
snflk/ts/ts-prod/2020/06/08/file_b.csv
snflk/ts/ts-prod/2020/06/09/file_b.csv
snflk/ts/ts-prod3/2020/06/08/file_b.csv
snflk/ts/ts-prod3/2020/06/09/file_b.csv
snflk/ts/ts-prod2/2020/06/08/file_b.csv
snflk/ts/ts-prod2/2020/06/09/file_b.csv
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to load only the current date files
>
> `.*/file_a.*[.]csv`
>
> this gets me all files from all dates

The pattern (`.*`) supplied at the beginning here is a wildcard that will match everything available.

If you need to limit the date to a constant value, specify the constant values inside the [regular expression pattern](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#optional-parameters) (i.e. `ts-prod.*/2020/06/09/file_a\.csv`, `ts-prod.*/2020/06/09/file_b\.csv`, etc.):

```sql
select
  metadata$filename
from @stage/snflk/ts/
(pattern=>'ts-prod.*/2020/06/09/file_a\.csv');
```

To iteratively test and write your regex patterns, you can use web tools such as [Regex101](https://regex101.com/), [RegExr](https://regexr.com/), etc.

**P.s.** You can also construct the pattern to [use the current date dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62294255/adding-current-date-in-create-script-for-snowflake/62294347#62294347), if you are trying to automate this:

```sql
-- Produces 'ts-prod.*/2020/06/11/file_a\.csv'
SET curr_dt_a=(
  SELECT 
    'ts-prod.*/' || 
    TO_VARCHAR(CURRENT_DATE(), 'YYYY/MM/DD') || 
    '/file_a\\.csv'
)

-- Referenced as a SQL variable in the PATTERN option
SELECT
  metadata$filename
FROM @stage/snflk/ts/
(PATTERN=>$curr_dt_a);
```

Comment: Thanks, the above regex didn't work out .. Made slight changes and it worked                                               `select
  metadata$filename
from @stage/snflk/ts/
(pattern=>'.*/2020/06/09/file_a.csv');`

Comment: Your detailed explanation is worth a lot. Thanks

Comment: This solution only works for a specific date. What if the files to be loaded are between 2 different dates? I just posted this question and wonder if it is possible to do that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65622872/snowflake-how-to-load-files-through-stage-from-ms-azure-using-specific-pattern