# Snowflake: how to load files through stage from MS Azure using specific pattern?

Tags: python, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I need to load files from MS Azure to Snowflake tables on a weekly basis, and I wonder if I can find a more efficient way of doing it

For example, if i want to load the files in this dir:

```
my_folder/food/20200101.csv 
... 
my_folder/food/20201201.csv
```

and name of the stage is
`my_stage`

then if i want to load the files for the month of June, the query would be:

```
select * from @my_stage (pattern => 'my_folder/food/202006.*.csv')
```

My question is, what if I want to load the files between 11/28/2020 and 12/05/2020?

The current method I am using is to separate the pattern like this:

```
pattern => 'my_folder/food/2020112[8-9].*.csv|my_folder/food/2020113[0-1].*.csv|my_folder/food/2020120[1-5].*.csv
```

Is there a way to make it simpler? like using >= and <= in the pattern?

Thanks and please let me know if my question lacks clarity. :)

Answer (score 1):

Inside the PATTERN-clause you can use Regex-expressions. I think using a Regex-expression for a date range may become quite complex and your solution is the simplest one. Maybe also looping over the files may help in your case.

More infos about the PATTERN-clause: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#optional-parameters