Snowflake filenaming while using copy into location instead of data_UUID to specific naming.csv
Below copy into creates file in s3 with filename data_17658djhgu167658.csv
Need input on naming files with specific contractid.csv when unloading data to s3.TIA
COPY INTO @DEV_TEST/TEST_AMOUNT/LOANS/2024/11/Q4_2024_TEST/
                                FROM (
                                SELECT 
                                        *
                                FROM DEV.TEST_DATA )
                                PARTITION BY ('contractid' || ContractID)
                                FILE_FORMAT=(
                                    TYPE = CSV
                                    ESCAPE = NONE
                                    ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = NONE
                                    COMPRESSION = NONE
                                    NULL_IF='NULL'
                                )
                                HEADER = TRUE
                                
                                MAX_FILE_SIZE = 5000000000
                                
                                ;```


There are several examples in SO, you can read this answer => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61597017/how-can-i-add-datetime-stamp-to-zip-file-when-unload-data-from-snowflake-to-s3

This is from documentation =>
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location
The optional path parameter specifies a folder and filename prefix for the file(s) containing unloaded data. If a filename prefix is not included in path or if the PARTITION BY parameter is specified, the filenames for the generated data files are prefixed with data_.

There is the parameter "Single=True" that would remove the UUID part from the file that is being unloaded to S3 using the "copy into" command.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location
but for the custom filename, I think you will need a Stored Proc to achieve that during the file unload operation.
